# Failing to show images in templates Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I have problems showing images in my Django templates (I'm uploading the images from the admin application). I read the documentation and other posts about the `upload_to` and still couldn't figure it out. I tried this `<img src="{{ a.image}}"/>` in my template and then this `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ a.image}}"/>` and same results. Here is my settings.py code :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/mohamed/code/eclipse workspace/skempi0/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and finally, I tried the following in my models.py and I failed miserably:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "ads/")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = ".")
```

and when I used `image = models.ImageField(upload_to = MEDIA_URL)` I got the following error

```
SuspiciousOperation at /admin/advertisments/banner/add/
Attempted access to '/media/cut.jpg' denied.
```

**EDIT**

Generated links are as follows :

```
<img src="./DSCN6671.JPG">
```

**RE-EDIT**

Here is my view:

```
def index(request):
spotlightAlbum =  Album.objects.filter(spotlight = True)
spotlightSong = Song.objects.filter(spotlight = True).order_by('numberOfPlays')
homepage = Song.objects.filter(homepage = True).order_by('numberOfPlays')
ads = Banner.objects.all()
copyright = CopyrightPage.objects.get()


try:
    user = User.objects.get(userSlug = "mohamed-turki")
    playlists = UserPlaylist.objects.filter(owner = user.userFacebookId)
    purchase = Purchase.objects.filter(userName = user.userFacebookId)
    user.loginState = 1

    user.save()
except:
    user = None
    playlists = None


context = {'copyright':copyright,  'ads':ads, 'spotlightSong':spotlightSong,'spotlightAlbum': spotlightAlbum, 'homepage':homepage, 'user':user, 'playlists':playlists, 'purchase':purchase }
return render_to_response('index.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Could anybody tell me what am I doing wrong??
P.S I'm using Django 1.4

Comment: When you use <img src={{ a.image }}" /> and the other method, what happens if you actually navigate to the given URL in your browser? Can you find the images in your browser without a link?

Comment: Please show generated image links and where images are actually uploaded to

Answer (score 1):

The path you provide in `upload_to` will be a relative path from the `MEDIA_ROOT` you set in your project's settings file (typically `settings.py`).

Your `MEDIA_ROOT` is where your uploaded media will be stored on disk while the `MEDIA_URL` is the URL from which Django will serve them.

So if your `MEDIA_ROOT` is `/home/mohamed/code/eclipse workspace/skempi0/media` and your model's image attribute is:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "ads/")
```

Then the final home on disk of your uploaded image will be `/home/mohamed/code/eclipse workspace/skempi0/media/ads/whatever-you-named-your-file.ext` and the URL it will be served from is `/media/ads/whatever-you-named-your-file.ext`

Setting your upload path to be `settings.MEDIA_URL` won't work because that's where the media is served FROM not where it is allowed to be stored on disk.

If you want to load your uploaded image in your templates just do this (replace `whatever` with the name of the variable sent from the view to the template that represents this object):

```
<img src="{{ whatever.image.url }}"/>
```

The image attribute on your model isn't actually an image, it's a Python class that represents an image. One of the methods on that `ImageField` class is `.url()` which constructs the path to the URL of the image taking into account how you set your `MEDIA_URL` in your project's settings. So the snippet above will generate HTML like this:

```
<img src="/media/ads/whatever-you-named-your-file.ext"/>
```

### RequestContext() and settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Since the `render_to_response()` you are returning from your view is utilizing `RequestContext()` you need to make sure you have `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` set correctly. [Check out the 1.4 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) for further clarification.

Comment: I failed miserably again. I tried everything you mentioned but same problem. This is driving me crazy !

Comment: Have you tried querying the object from the shell (`python manage.py shell`) to see if it works there?

Comment: Yes, here is a sample :
`>>> from advertisments.models import *`
`>>> img = Banner.objects.get()`
`>>> img.title`
`u'sdfsfsf'`
`>>> img.image`
`<ImageFieldFile: images/IMG_25042012_091454.png>`
`>>> img.image.url`
`'/media/images/IMG_25042012_091454.png'`
`>>>` 
`

Comment: It looks like everything is working fine in the shell so, if it's not working in your templates there's probably something amiss in your project configuration.

Are you developing locally? What does you settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS look like? Also, what does your view code look like, are you using `render_to_response()`?

Comment: I don't have that line TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in my settings, should it be there in Django 1.4? Also, please see the newly edited original post to see my view.

Comment: I added this information to my answer but thought I'd include it here as well: Since your `render_to_response()` is utilizing `RequestContext()` you need to make sure you have settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS set correctly. [Check out the 1.4 docs for further clarification](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Answer (score 0):

`upload_to` needs to be an absolute path to the *directory*, not the web url. So try this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in your templates, just use

```
<img src="{{ a.image.url }}">
```

Comment: I tried this, when I'm uploading the picture i get the SuspiciousOperation error.

Comment: Ok, there must be something else wrong then. I wonder if the space in your MEDIA_ROOT is causing the problem? The code as I've written it should definitely work.

Comment: I tried the same thing with a different location (without space) and I had the same error "SuspiciousOperation" when I was uploading the image from the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest to change the MEDIA_ROOT to be

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media')
```

this way you ensure the media directory path is right under your project root. Your MEDIA_URL is set up correctly, but it is not used when uploading a file. MEDIA_ROOT is.

Regarding the file upload, in your model set the field to be

```
image_field = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='images/some_sub_folder')
```

**Note** that I didn't use neither a leading nor trailing forward slashes. The above will upload the image to `PROJECT_ROOT/media/images/some_sub_folder/` with the filename and extension of the original file. Alternatively, you can alter the filename by using a callable - `upload_to=filename_convetion` - more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

In your template, you can access the image using

```
<img src="/media/{{ your_model.image_field }}" />
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me either. I could successfully upload the image from the admin panel but it doesn't show in the template. Even when I tried to access the image from the full path in my browser, or when I provided the full path to the template, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had the same problem and this solved in my case:

## settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

## urls.py

Then, my urls.py was missing this line of code to discover the /media/ folder and show the content:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}, name="media_url"),
) + urlpatterns
```

Hope it can help someone.